# Angular and Firebase Cloud Messaging build error

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on an angular project with FCM for notifications but my app won't build anymore. I have per now read everything i can find on the subject and shaped my code thereafter, but I am still getting the same error.

> building modules 3/3 modules 0 activeFailed on type {"filePath":"C:/Users/SlyOtis/Documents/Time2Work/src/frontend/src/app/_services/firebase.service.ts","name":"FCMService","members":[]} with error Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Exp
>   ression form not supported (position 15:57 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol FCMService in C:/Users/SlyOtis/Documents/Time2Work/src/frontend/src/app/_services/firebase.service.ts
>
> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported (position 15:57 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol FCMService in C:/Users/SlyOtis/Documents/Time2Work/src/frontend/src/app/_services/firebase.service.ts

#### firebase.service.ts

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseApp} from 'angularfire2';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {StorageService} from './storage.service';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Injectable()
export class FCMService {

  private currentToken = '';
  private readonly messaging: firebase.messaging.Messaging;
  private readonly subject: Subject<any>;

  constructor(@Inject(FirebaseApp) private firebaseApp: firebase.app.App,
              private storage: StorageService) {

    this.messaging = firebase.messaging(this.firebaseApp);
    this.subject = new Subject();

    this.messaging.onTokenRefresh(this.onTokenRefresh);
    this.messaging.onMessage(this.onMessage);

    const tmpToken = storage.get('fcm_token');
    if (tmpToken) {
      this.currentToken = <string>tmpToken;
    } else {
      // this.init();
    }
  }

  public init() {
    this.requestPermission();
    this.getToken();
  }

  public requestToken() {
    this.getToken();
  }

  public getObservableSubject(): Subject<any> {
    return this.subject;
  }

  private onMessage(payload: any) {
    console.log('Message received. ', payload);
    // TODO:: Add message structur and observable.
    this.subject.next(payload);
    this.storage.putObject('msg', payload);
  }

  private onTokenRefresh() {
    const token = this.messaging.getToken();
    if (token !== null) {
      token.then(refreshedToken => {
        console.log('Token refreshed.');
        this.sendTokenToServer(refreshedToken);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ');
    }
  }

  private getToken() {

    const token = this.messaging.getToken();
    if (token !== null) {
      token.then(currentToken => {
        if (currentToken) {
          this.sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
        } else {
          // Show permission request.
          console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        }
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ');
    }
  }
  // Send the Instance ID token your application server, so that it can:
  // - send messages back to this app
  // - subscribe/unsubscribe the token from topics
  private sendTokenToServer(currentToken: any) {
    console.log('Current token: ' + currentToken);
  }

  private requestPermission() {
    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    const permission = this.messaging.requestPermission();
    if (permission !== null) {
      permission.then(() => {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        this.getToken();
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to getObject permission to notify.', err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Unable to getObject permission to notify.');
    }
  }

  private deleteToken() {
    const token = this.messaging.getToken();
    if (token !== null) {
      token.then((currentToken: string) => {
        const deleted = this.messaging.deleteToken(currentToken);
        if (deleted !== null) {
          deleted.then(() => {
            console.log('Token deleted.');
            this.getToken();
          })
          .catch(function(err: any) {
            console.log('Unable to delete token. ', err);
          });
      } else {
          console.log('Unable to delete token. ');
        }}).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ');
    }
  }
}
```

#### firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'ÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆ',
  authDomain: 'ØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØØ',
  databaseURL: 'ÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅÅ',
  projectId: 'asdasdasdasdasd',
  storageBucket: 'asdasdasdasdasdasdasd',
  messagingSenderId: '420'
};
// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

The project works well with `ng serve` but not with `build`, any idea of what im doing wrong?

Comment: can you post full service file firebase.service.ts including headers

Comment: there you go :)

Comment: try impore firebasefrom like this  import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';